# CGEL style fusion of functions trees using Forest in TeXstudio

Tags: forest, trees

How do I draw a *CGEL*-style fused determiner-head in an NP. This get's the basic shape of it, but I'd like everything from the Determiner-Head down to be centred under the NP at the top and an edge from Nom down to Head, as shown in the second (manipulated) image below.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [\textsf{Supplement}\\NP, s sep=0
            [\textsf{Determiner-Head}\\DP, l*=2.55
                [\textsf{Head}\\D
                    [\textit{which}]]
                ]
            ]
            [\textsf{Head}\\Nom
                    [,phantom]
            ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: A badly drawn syntax tree showing an NP with a Head Nom and a fused determiner-head.]
[image: The corrected tree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following answer from [@qpheevr on Twitter](https://twitter.com/qpheevr/status/1406311060991352833?s=20).

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
[\textsf{Supplement}\\NP,s sep=-2em
[\phantom{X}\hspace*{-4em},tier=dh]
[\textsf{Determiner-Head}\\DP,no edge,tier=dh
[\textsf{Head}\\D
[\textit{which}]
]
]
[\textsf{Head}\\Nom
[\hspace*{-4em}\phantom{X},tier=dh]
]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alignment of children with respect to their parent is controlled by key `calign`, which is given to the parent node. In OP's case, we want the first child to be aligned to the parent, so we say `calign=first`. (I took the liberty to reformat a bit, as OP's `l*` leads to problems by pushing the DP too much down.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [\textsf{Supplement}\\NP, calign=first, l sep*=2,
    [\textsf{Determiner-Head}\\DP
      [\textsf{Head}\\D
        [\textit{which}]
      ]
    ]
    [\textsf{Head}\\Nom]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same effect could be achieved by saying `calign with current` on the child node (DP). For more info on `calign`, see section 3.7.2 of the Forest manual.

Comment: The information about caling is useful, but I guess I wasn't clear about my intended result. I've now uploaded a second tree to show what I'm trying to do. I've played around with calign, but I don't see how it can achieve this.